# cmd prompt freezes until I hit CTRL+C, then continues as normal

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cmd, npm

I'm having a weird issue.

I'm trying to set up a project I downloaded. The project is a web application with server components in `Node.js` and client components in `Angular`.

When I do things like `npm install` in command prompt, it just freezes at `_`, until I hit `CTRL+C`, when it resumes and everything executes succesfully.

This is really strange. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: If this is windows, if you select something in the cmd window while it is running it will pause (not show more display) until you clear that. This will happen via ctrl+c or by hitting enter

Comment: is it waiting for some input? tried hitting enter?

Comment: Can you perhaps show a little more of the output leading up to the freeze? A single underscore is not a lot to go by.

Comment: @MarcB yes, hitting `Enter` also makes it continue

Comment: Thanks @ruffin, same solution outlined here - [python program stops in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571981/python-program-stops-in-command-line) (caused me much pain ;) )

Comment: And here - [Sometimes PowerShell stops sending output until I press enter. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571981/python-program-stops-in-command-line)

Answer (score 6):

I've had a number of freezes after an `npm i` that, even if I scorch the node_modules folder & npm cache (`rmdir /S /Q node_modules` and then `npm cache clean --force`), can still happen and that don't seem to happen at predictable times.

[Here's one possible answer from the nodejs project's github issues pages](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/8196#issuecomment-297747376), edited slightly to match what I see now in Win10:

> This "Randomly" hang issue is causing by CMD when you trying to
> highlight inside of CMD. To resolve this issue:
>
> 1. right click title bar
> 2. select Defaults
> 3. **unselect Quick Edit Mode from the Options tab**
> 4. reopen CMD

Though note that ***you*** don't have to actively highlight anything for npm to stop; I'm going to guess something npm executes is "highlighting" some text as part of its log to the console and that interaction throws off cmd ([as Brocco implied in 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230255/cmd-prompt-freezes-until-i-hit-ctrlc-then-continues-as-normal/57630309#comment42937542_27230255) and [ArbitraryChoices seemed to confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230255/cmd-prompt-freezes-until-i-hit-ctrlc-then-continues-as-normal/57630309#comment133563386_65362950) yesterday).

I've given turning off Quick Edit Mode a try with some success. I think the downside is limited to you having have to hit `Alt-space, e, k` to select text with the mouse like you did before Quick Edit Mode was foisted on us.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from ruffin seems to be correct. I experienced the same thing. The ping display would just stop, and then Ctrl-C would make it resume. Turning off Quick-Edit mode solved the problem. However, I should also add:

I never had this issue until recently (that is, early December, 2020). It just started happening, seemingly out of the blue. I did not recently (or ever, that I recall) turn on Quick Edit mode. Therefore, my guess is that a recent Windows Update has changed the settings making Quick Edit on the default setting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30517482/7874617 The reason is well explained here